# Producing txt file from mail merge with Title

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to go through a mail merge and produce a .txt with each entry. The .txt file should have the title that corresponds to one of my fields in the mail merge (trying to get it with `ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields(1))`. Currently my script does not run however does not produce an error.

If anyone had an advice it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Current code:

```
Option Explicit   

Sub AllSectionsToSubDoc()
  Dim x               As Long
  Dim Sections        As Long
  Dim Doc             As Document

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Set Doc = ActiveDocument
  Sections = Doc.Sections.Count
  For x = Sections - 1 To 1 Step -1
    Doc.Sections(x).Range.Copy
    Documents.Add
    ActiveDocument.Range.Paste
    Call ActiveDocument.SaveAs(Doc.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields(1) & ".txt", wdFormatText)
    ActiveDocument.Close False
  Next x

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Call ActiveDocument.SaveAs(Doc.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Result & ".txt", wdFormatText)
```

or

```
Call ActiveDocument.SaveAs(Doc.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.Sections(x).Fields(1).Result & ".txt", wdFormatText)
```

or/and change the number of fields if required.